# Why my routing on the server does not work - with Laravel 6.0?

Tags: php, laravel, cpanel

Normally everything works fine on localhost. When I throw the project to the server, only the homepage works.

When I add manually to this section from the database, I can pull the data.
web site here: http://elsetea.com/public (running)
but when I want to log in to my admin panel from this page (http://elsetea.com/public/login) routing does not work properly and it gives an error.

Why can you think? Please help me. Very Thanks.

Username: admin@admin.com
Password: admin

You can see some routing below.

```
    web.php
        Auth:

:routes();


    Route::namespace('Frontend')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'HomeController@index')->name('home.index');
      //  Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
    });

    Route::namespace('Frontend')->group(function () {
        Route::get('service', 'ServicePageController@index')->name('service-page.index');
    });

    Route::namespace('Frontend')->group(function () {
        Route::get('portfolio', 'PortfolioPageController@index')->name('portfolio-page.index');
        Route::get('portfolio/{slug}', 'PortfolioPageController@show')->name('portfolio-page.show');
    });

    Route::namespace('Frontend')->group(function () {
        Route::post('comment', 'CommentController@store')->name('comment.store');
    });

    Route::namespace('Frontend')->group(function () {
        Route::post('contact', 'ContactPageController@store')->name('contact-page.store');
    });

    Route::namespace('Frontend')->group(function () {
        Route::get('aboutus', 'AboutusPageController@index')->name('aboutus-page.index');
    });

    Route::namespace('Frontend')->group(function () {
        Route::get('blog', 'BlogPageController@index')->name('blog-page.index');
        Route::get('blog/{slug}', 'BlogPageController@show')->name('blog-page.show');
        Route::get('blog/category/{category_name}', 'BlogPageController@category_show')->name('blog-category.show');
    });







    Route::middleware(['auth.admin'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('admin-panel/dashboard', 'HomeController@index')->name('dashboard');
    });

    Route::namespace('Admin')->middleware(['auth.admin'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('admin-panel/profile/edit', 'ProfileController@edit')->name('profile.edit');
        Route::put('admin-panel/profile/{id}', 'ProfileController@update')->name('profile.update');
        Route::get('admin-panel/profile/change-password', 'ProfileController@change_password_edit')->name('profile.change_password_edit');
        Route::put('admin-panel/profile/change-password/update', 'ProfileController@change_password_update')->name('profile.change_password_update');
    });

    Route::namespace('Admin')->middleware(['auth.admin'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('admin-panel/site-info', 'SiteInfoController@create')->name('site-info.create');
        Route::post('admin-panel/site-info', 'SiteInfoController@store')->name('site-info.store');
        Route::put('admin-panel/site-info/{id}', 'SiteInfoController@update')->name('site-info.update');
    });

    Route::namespace('Admin')->middleware(['auth.admin'])->group(function () {
        Route::get('admin-panel/homepage-version', 'HomepageVersionController@create')->name('homepage-version.create');
        Route::post('admin-panel/homepage-version', 'HomepageVersionController@store')->name('homepage-version.store');
        Route::put('admin-panel/homepage-version/{id}', 'HomepageVersionController@update')->name('homepage-version.update');
    });
```

Comment: What hosting environment are you using? public shouldn't be in the path? Are you using apache or nginx?

Comment: Project directory this way (https://prnt.sc/r6kcin). I perform operations from a c panel with a Linux infrastructure.

Comment: Nginx PHP-FPM technology is using the provider.